# In Gradient Descent algorithm, how to induce -2*wx

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, gradient-descent

[part of Gradient Descent algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTBz6.png)

```
this.updateWeights = function() {
 
  let wx;
  let w_deriv = 0;
  let b_deriv = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < this.points; i++) {
    wx = this.yArr[i] - (this.weight * this.xArr[i] + this.bias);
    w_deriv += -2 * wx * this.xArr[i];
    b_deriv += -2 * wx;
  }
  
  this.weight -= (w_deriv / this.points) * this.learnc;
  this.bias -= (b_deriv / this.points) * this.learnc;
}
```

explain this part please!!

```
-2 * wx * this.xArr[i]
```

this part is induced....?

how to induce by math formula....

Answer (score 0):

It's derived from the partial derivative of the MSE loss function with respect to `w`. I wrote a simplified induction process on paper, hoping it's helpful. [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wQdS.jpg)